# my code for ajax auto complete extender is not working when using with data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

this is .aspx code

```
  <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods = "true"></asp:ScriptManager>
      <asp:TextBox ID="SearchTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="1"  
                    CompletionInterval="10" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="1" TargetControlID="SearchTextBox"  
                    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false">  
                </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender> 
                 </div>
```

this is my cs page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class UserMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        ConnectionClass cl = new ConnectionClass();
        DataTable dt = cl.AutoComplete(prefixText);
        List<string> Topics = new List<string>();
        using (dt)
        {
            int r = dt.Rows.Count;
            while (r > 0)
            {
                Topics.Add(dt.Rows[r].ItemArray[0].ToString());
                r--;
            }
        }
        return Topics;
}
}
```

this is my connection class-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1
/// </summary>
public class ConnectionClass
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    string str;
    public ConnectionClass()
    {
        str = @"Data source=INSPIRATION\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=ComputerPedia; Integrated security= true";
    }
    public void establishConnection()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(str);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        con.Open();
    }
    public void closeConnection()
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Close();
    }
    public void createReaderCommand(string sql)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    public SqlDataReader executeReaderCommand()
    {
        dr.Read();
        return dr;
    }
    public DataTable AutoComplete(string topic)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Topic");
        establishConnection();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("AutoComplete", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@topic", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = topic;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        closeConnection();
        return dt;
    }
}
```

my stored procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[AutoComplete]
(
@topic nvarchar(20)
)
as
begin
select distinct Topic from Tutorials where Topic like @topic + '%'
end
```

my auto complete extender is not working. the procedure is working fine in sql server!. please help me. i don't know what mistake i have done. Thanks in advance!

Comment: where are you passing count to getcompletionlist?

Comment: i dont know how to implement this?

Comment: is debug point firing to that method?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your  GetCompletionlist as follows and also set `CompletionInterval="0"`

```
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        List<string> Topics = new List<string>();
        ConnectionClass cl = new ConnectionClass();
        DataTable dt = cl.AutoComplete(prefixText);
             int i;
       for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
           {
               Topics.Add(dt.Rows[i]["ColumnName"].ToString());//Try to give the column name of the resultset from the datatable
           }


        return Topics;
}
```

Comment: i added my stored procedure

Comment: @SharaRizvi you need to add stored procedure to your question but not to my answer

Comment: sorry i m adding that

Comment: i added that.. please see to it